# Need to change hmvc routes in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes, hmvc

I have CodeIgniter HMVC application and I want to change route as per  requirement.

Now I have website/product/detail/url, and I want to change it with website/url.

Once I set URL from admin side it will redirect to my route.

This is what I have now:

```
$route['Products'] = "Products/detail/d101productdatatest(this is url)";
```

And I want in my url like `website/url` and it will open same page what I have with `website/product/detail/url`

Comment: did you think this through ? as far as i see you want your product description as first segment after your url isn't it ? the only way i can imagine is, to wait for the router if it found anything - and if not you route to your desired controller... (it has some drawbacks though...)

Answer (score 0):

**From the given library:**

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

**routes as above:**

```
$route['controller/function'] ='website/Products/detail/d101productdatatest';
```

But as per your given question:

- you cannot manipulate url using routes
- you can map same function with different url using routes
- you have to use .htaccess to redirect to specific url after hitting the previous given url.

**htaccess example:**

```
Redirect /index.html /new/
Redirect /index.html /default.html
Redirect /private/ http://www.example.com/private/
Redirect /img/logo.gif http://www.example.com/images/logo.gif
```

Hope this answer helps you out !!
cheers

Comment: i have this website/Products/detail/d101productdatatest

and i want 

website/d101productdatatest and  output will same

Comment: @nikunj check the answer

Comment: @nikunj tell me your controller and function name and which library are you using for hmvc